# Text Game project for IT 140

Tags: python, game, adventure-game

So this is my first time taking a coding class. It's my second project for my IT140 class and I am making a text based game. This is my code so far. I do have a warning on Pycharm for

> Shadows name `current_room` from outer scope on [lines 23, 76, 84]

but I haven't seen it create any issue so far when running the game. Thanks for any tips or suggestions!

```py
# DKozzy

# Define the room dictionary and other global variables
rooms = {
    'Entrance to the Crypt': {'North': 'Research Room'},
    'Research Room': {'North': 'Chamber of Shadows', 'East': 'Bed Chambers', 'West': 'Treasury', 'South':
                      'Entrance to the Crypt', 'Item': 'Tome of Dark Incantations'},
    'Treasury': {'East': 'Research Room', 'Item': 'Amulet of Undead Warding'},
    'Bed Chambers': {'West': 'Research Room', 'Item': 'Phylactery Orb'},
    'Chamber of Shadows': {'East': 'Armory', 'North': 'Throne Room', 'South': 'Research Room',
                           'Item': 'Orb of Shadow Veil'},
    'Armory': {'West': 'Chamber of Shadows', 'Item': 'Soul Reaper Scythe'},
    'Throne Room': {'South': 'Chamber of Shadows', 'West': 'Ritual Sanctum', 'Item': 'Cursed Crown of Dominion'},
    'Ritual Sanctum': {'East': 'Throne Room'}
}

current_room = 'Entrance to the Crypt'
player_inventory = []
Lich_King_room = 'Ritual Sanctum'


# Define the get_new_state function
def get_new_state(direction_from_user, current_room):
    global player_inventory
    global rooms

    if direction_from_user in rooms[current_room]:
        new_room = rooms[current_room][direction_from_user]
        print("You moved to", new_room)

        # Check if the new room has an item
        if 'Item' in rooms[new_room]:
            item = rooms[new_room]['Item']
            print("You found an item:", item)

        return new_room
    else:
        print("You can't go that way.")
        return current_room


# Function to display game instructions
def show_instructions():
    instructions = (
        "The Lich King's Terror!\n"
        "Collect 6 items to win the game.\n"
        "Move commands: go North, go South, go East, go West\n"
        "Get item command: get [item name]\n"
        "Check status command: status"
    )
    print(instructions)


# Function to display player's status
def show_status():
    global current_room
    print("Current Room:", current_room)

    if 'Item' in rooms[current_room]:
        print("Item in Room:", rooms[current_room]['Item'])
    else:
        print("No item in this room.")

    print("Inventory:", player_inventory)

    print("Available Directions:")
    available_directions = rooms[current_room].keys()
    available_directions = [direction for direction in available_directions if direction != 'Item']
    print(", ".join(available_directions))


# Main function containing the gameplay loop
def main():
    show_instructions()

    current_room = 'Entrance to the Crypt'  # Initialize current room here
    while True:
        command = input('Enter a command: ').lower()
        action, *params = command.split()

        if action == 'go':
            direction = params[0].capitalize()
            if direction in rooms[current_room]:
                current_room = get_new_state(direction, current_room)  # Pass current_room as parameter
            else:
                print('Invalid direction!')
        elif action == 'get':
            if len(params) == 0:
                print('Please specify the item name.')
            else:
                item_name = ' '.join(params).lower()  # Input item name to lowercase
                # Check if the item exists in the current room
                if 'Item' in rooms[current_room]:
                    room_item = rooms[current_room]['Item']
                    if item_name.lower() == room_item.lower():
                        player_inventory.append(room_item)
                        del rooms[current_room]['Item']
                        print(f'You obtained the {room_item} from this room.')
                    else:
                        print('Item not found in this room.')
                else:
                    print('No item in this room.')
        elif action == 'status':
            show_status()  # Uses the show_status function here
        elif action == 'quit':
            break
        else:
            print('Uh... What kind of command was that?')

        # Check win condition
        if len(player_inventory) == 6 and current_room == Lich_King_room:
            print('Congratulations!\n'
                  'You have collected all items and defeated the Lich King.\n'
                  'You have saved the world!\n'
                  'You win!')
            break

        # Check lose condition
        if current_room == Lich_King_room and len(player_inventory) < 6:
            print("You encounter the Lich King, but you don't have all the required items to stop his treachery.\n"
                  'You lose!')
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 6):

Wow, this is pretty good!

## shadowing

> a warning on Pycharm for "Shadows name 'current_room' from outer scope" ... but I haven't seen it create any issue so far when running the game.

You actually *do* want to tidy up that detail.
There's no point in writing code which will confuse the author.

First, let's touch on a vocabulary word: "to shadow".
Here's an example, a terrible horrible example:

```
x = 1
print = 7
print(x)
```

What happens here?
That's right, it blows up with TypeError.
There *used* to be a python object that was a very
nice function which will print out its argument.
Actually it's still there.
You just can't see it, because
it is shadowed by an `int` with the same name.
We can evaluate `print + 1` and get `8`.
But we can no longer call the `print()` function,
not easily.

Don't do that.

Avoid shadowing names.
It leads to confusion, incorrect results, or both.

```
current_room = 'Entrance to the Crypt'
...
def show_status():
    global current_room
...
def main():
    show_instructions()

    current_room = 'Entrance to the Crypt'  # Initialize current room here
```

The name of your module is `__main__`, and
you created a `current_room` string at module scope.
Which `show_status()` accesses via `global` (not that it needed that).
Over in `main()` you create a **completely different** `str` object
having the **same name**.
Don't do that.
And then you sometimes pass it in as a parameter,
for example in the signature of `get_new_state()`.

Pick a place for that variable to live,
either as a module scope global or as a `main()` local
that gets passed around,
and consistently stick with that decision.

In descending order of preference, *I* would put it

- in an object attribute after defining a class: `self.current_room`
- a `main()` local variable that gets passed around via function signatures
- a module scope global

Any one of those would work.

A function that just reads a global typically
doesn't need that `global` keyword,
since cPython will search the function namespace and,
upon no match, will then search the enclosing module namespace
and locate your variable.

A function that writes to a global definitely needs a `global` keyword.
Otherwise we'll create a function local variable of the same name,
shadowing the global and failing to update it.
My preference is to avoid use of the `global` keyword
wherever feasible, to reduce coupling and to encourage good designs.

## comments

We use code to reveal **how** to compute a result,
and we use a `#` comment to reveal **why** we chose
to compute it that way.

```
# Define the get_new_state function
def get_new_state( ...
```

Here, the code has already spoken eloquently,
and the `#` comment adds nothing.
Elide it.

## docstrings

```
# Main function containing the gameplay loop
def main():
```

This is a helpful comment, explaining that the function's
[single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)
is to run the main gameplay loop,
something that isn't self-evident just from the identifier.

Python has a special way for author to express such things.
It's called a """docstring""".
Let's turn that comment into a docstring.

```
def main():
    """Main is responsible for running the gameplay loop."""
```

---

Keep writing code, keep paying attention to code quality,
and you'll be writing giant python programs in no time!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I was murky on the subject matter, and have since rectified the issue you've sighted.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, the code layout is good, and you chose meaningful names for variables and functions.  When I run it, the instructions are easy to follow.

The layout of the `rooms` assignment is a bit ad-hoc.  I think it is easier to read and maintain if you put each direction and item on a separate line, something like:

```
rooms = {
    'Entrance to the Crypt': {'North': 'Research Room'},
    'Research Room': {  'North': 'Chamber of Shadows', 
                        'East' : 'Bed Chambers',
                        'West' : 'Treasury', 
                        'South': 'Entrance to the Crypt',
                        'Item' : 'Tome of Dark Incantations'},
```

When I run [pylint](https://docs.pylint.org/index.html), it reports potential issues like the global variables and missing comments that the [other answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/289621/125403) addresses.  I recommend you run it yourself.

When I run the code, I think I might see a bug.  Consider the following transcript:

```
Enter a command: status
Current Room: Entrance to the Crypt
No item in this room.
Inventory: ['Tome of Dark Incantations', 'Orb of Shadow Veil', 'Cursed Crown of Dominion']
Available Directions:
North
Enter a command: go north
Invalid direction!
Enter a command:
```

The `status` command seems to tell me the only available direction is north, but when I then enter the command `go north`, it tells me it is an invalid direction.  Is this a bug?

If I look earlier in the transcript, I also noticed this inconsistency with the room I am in:

```
You moved to Research Room
You found an item: Tome of Dark Incantations
Enter a command: get tome of dark incantations
You obtained the Tome of Dark Incantations from this room.
Enter a command: status
Current Room: Entrance to the Crypt
```

First it tells me I'm in the `Research Room`, but the subsequent status contradicts that and says I'm in the `Entrance to the Crypt`.  Am I interpreting this the right way?

Comment: Thank you for your insight, I've since rectified that error. I also took your advice on the rooms assignment and it is much simpler to read. Again thank you for your input